# Getting a mimetype error when serving two apps on one domain

Tags: nginx

I have two node apps running at two different ports.

To get nginx to appropriately route requests, I have two location blocks,

```
# /etc/nginx/sites-available/my_site.com
server {
    root /var/www/my_site.com/html;
    index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;

    server_name my_site.com www.my_site.com;

    location / {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5001;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }

    location /app2 {
            proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_redirect off;
    }
    listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
    listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_site.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/my_site.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

Now, the app running at port `5001` works fine. Trying to visit `my_site.com` or making requests to its API services through postman works as expected.

However, the moment I try to visit my second app `app2` that is running on port `5000`, I am met with a blank white screen and the following in my console:

```
Refused to execute script from 'https://my_site.com/path/to/static/js/main.61886448.chunk.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I've verified that these files that the client is trying to access exist and that the `http` block in `nginx.conf` includes the following line,

```
http {
    . . .
    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    . . .
}
```

My frontend app attempts to make requests `https://my_site.com/path/to/static` with a successful 200 response code, indicating, to me at least, that the path itself is correct.

What am I doing wrong here? If you're wondering, why my `app2` location block is as empty as it is, it's because I kept getting `304 redirect` status codes, instead of 200.

I'm equally unable to hit my healthcheck endpoint. It would have lived at `http://localhost:5000/api/health`, if I didn't have that second `location` block, but because I do, I try to make a request to `http://localhost:5000/app2/api/health` -- but this fails as well.

Comment: `https://my_site.com/path/to/static/js/main.61886448.chunk.js` is pointing to 5001 and not app2, so presumably you are getting an html response from 5001 as that file is unlikely to exist in the wrong app. Your app2 needs to prefix its resource URLs with `/app2/` to find the correct service.

Comment: Also, you should use `location /app2/ { proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/; ... }` to remove the `app2` prefix before passing the request to the service on 5000. Note that both the `location` and `proxy_pass` have a trailing `/`.

Comment: To respond to your first comment, I just double checked and the request is sent to `https://my_site.com/app2/client/build/static/css/main.6dea0f05.chunk.css` -- it seems as though the request is correct (the response is also 200 and not something like 404)

Comment: To respond to your second point, I've made the edits and the only difference now is that when I navigate to `http://my_site.com/app2`, it redirect me to `http://my_site.com/app2/` (notice the slash at the end). Everything else is the same, I'm getting that MIMEtype error

Comment: When you hit *`localhost:5000`* using **curl** inside your server what you see

Answer (score 1):

The error

> Refused to execute script from 'https://my_site.com/path/to/static/js/main.61886448.chunk.js' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.

is from the browser which says that it was expecting a javascript file in the response. Instead, it got something else (a blank `text/html` response may be). The path `'https://my_site.com/path/to/static/js/main.61886448.chunk.js'` doesn't satisfy the `/app2` rule and instead goes to the first location block which is sending a 200 status code html response (the error message might be inside the html elements).

The neatest solution would be to add `/app2/` prefix in all your resources in the application hosted on port `5000` as pointed out by *Richard* in the comments.

However, if you only care about static files you can write one more location block matching all static requests ending with `.js`, `.css`, `.png`, `.jpg`, etc.

```
location ~* .(png|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|css|js)$ {
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000;
}
```

This will ensure that your static files are served by **localhost:5000**.
Additionally, if the browser side application is making XHR requests to the backend you might need to add additional `location` blocks `proxy_pass`ing them to correct path.

About the last healthcheck endpoint error, it is coming because according to your `location` directive rule. According to your rule requests coming to `https://my_site.com/app2/api/health` will be proxied to `http://localhost:5000/app2/api/health` which will give you a 404 if the path `/app2/api/health` doesn't exist in your application. In order to proxy `https://my_site.com/app2/api/health` to `http://localhost:5000/api/health`, the correct rule should be:

```
location /app2/ {                        # <--- notice trailing slash here
    proxy_pass http://localhost:5000/;   # <--- notice trailing slash here
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_redirect off;
}
```